# iPhone 4S wth update 8.1.3

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

I updated my iPhone with the iOS update 8.1.3, and now I am unable to activate my phone because it shows a connect to iTunes screen with no other option.

Finally, when I connect to iTunes, it gives me a message to update or, if it is still not working, completely restore to factory settings.

Although there was no warning that this update is not suitable to my iPhone, now I have no other option than restoring my iPhone to factory settings. Worse, the update fails with error -39

***Question:*** How do I fix my iPhone since it will not start up at all and this error -39 doesn't help me know what's really wrong and if it's my iPhone or my Computer that needs fixing?

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your device in DFU mode, then restore it via iTunes. This method should work with you.

Comment: What is DFU mode?

Comment: Device firmware update mode. You turn it off, then hold down the home button and keep holding it while you quickly plug it in to a computer. This results in a slightly different sort of restore. 

Actually that's how it is done on iPads from generation 4 on. I haven't used older devices much, the iPhone 4S might be the old way described at [link](https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode)